# Continuous everywhere except one jump discontuity at the boundary?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Suppose that $f:\overline{\Omega}\subset\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ where $\Omega$ is an open bounded domain with smooth boundary. Is it possible that $f$ is continuous at every point in $\overline{\Omega}$ except for a jump discontinuity at $x_0\in\partial\Omega$ ?

By jump discontinuity I mean that if $\alpha:[0,1]\to \partial\Omega$ is a parametrization of $\partial\Omega$ such that $\alpha(t_0)=x_0$ for $t_0\in(0,1)$, then the function $f\circ\alpha$ has a jump discontinuity at the point $t_0$.

Visually I can't see how this is possible, so does anyone have an idea on how to approach this?

Edit: I think I might have found an example of such an $f$ that will have arbitrarily large gradient as $x\to x_0$ but it's hard to write. Can anyone confirm that this will be the case ? (that $\nabla f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to x_0$?)

Comment: If you let f be constant except at one point then it’s continuous everywhere except at that point. True for any space where points are closed.

Comment: Yes but then the discontinuity at this this point would not be a jump discontinuity, it will be a removable discontinuity

Comment: Please bear in mind tha what I'm asking for is that $$\lim_{t\to t_0^-}f(\alpha(t))\neq \lim_{t\to t_0^+}f(\alpha(t)).$$

Comment: Got it. Will leave my comment in case it clarifies for someone else.  I think it is possible, I’ll try to write it up formally as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega$ be the disk with radius $1$ and center $(1,0)$, and let $f(r,\theta) = \sin(\theta)$ Then this is continuous and well-defined away from $(0,0)$, but the limit approaching on the boundary from above the $x$ axis is $1$ while the limit approaching from the bottom is $-1$.

Comment: Your answer is correct if $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and not of $r$ and $\theta$. A better way to write your function is using complex numbers $f(z)=\sin(\text{arg}(z))$, which incidentally gives rise to a simpler example $f(z)=\text{arg}(z)$. Please improve your answer and I will accept it!

Comment: feel free to edit it